# Java Date pegando horario errado

Tags: java, data, timezone

Bom, estou com o seguinte problema em pegar o horário do sistema. em um processo java que estou trabalhando

Realizei os testes em uma determinada hora, e o método a baixo retornava 1 hora a mais

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    java.lang.System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

se eu fizesse essa ''gambiarra'' no codigo ele retornava o horário certo

```
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    TimeZone timeZone = mCalendar.getTimeZone();
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"+TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(timeZone.getRawOffset(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
    java.lang.System.out.println(date.toString());
```

queria saber se tem como ele mostrar o horário certo sem precisar recorrer a esse recurso, creio eu que que tenha algo a ver com essa confusão com o horário de verão que não teve esse ano

Comment: Eu tive este problema, na segunda feira, quando alguns relógios atualizaram para o horário de verão, qual navegador vc utiliza? O meu era o chrome e deu este problema, após atualizar ficou normal, pegando a hora correta.

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi a relação entre o chrome e o horário que eu pego no meu processo, poderia me explicar melhor?